# Cannot connect to SQL Server remotely

Tags: c#, sql-server, server

I'm Installing SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on my server, then I applied all of the remote rules to connect to this from my system.

But when I tried to connect to the SQL Server, I got errors. I created an account and did all of the steps in [this link](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/).

**TODO:** when I want to remotely connect to my server, I'm using PORT: 3390 - it means, I use `x.x.x.x:3390` to remotely connect. And when I want to remotely my SQL Server, I just use `x.x.x.x`

When I N-map my server IP, I got these results:

- 1723 open,
- 1900 filtered,
- 2000 open,
- 8080 open, also i don't see port 1433 is open.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: if someone can configure that , tell me also to give information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you connect to sql server on remote host locally? if you can, check your firewall configuration. you need to open ports

- 1433 TCP (for remote connect)
- 1434 UDP (for discovery)

Comment: i open those. but i faild. yes i can connect locally

Comment: then it is definitely firewall issue. If you are on firewall backed environment. such as company network, vpn, vs, you need to talk with  Network Administrator of the company

Comment: no there is. i turned off the firewall.can u config that if i give you ip and password?

Comment: is this server inside company network? without knowing environment I can't help you. but i can connect to your environment if you want

Comment: Its ok , give me ur Gmail. no its a cumpiter in our company with static ip

Comment: all of our company systems use that static ip

Comment: but your company has firewall right? did you talk with Network Admin of the company?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186631/discussion-between-reza-pak-and-simonare).